# If a particle's acceleration is positive and its velocity is negative, is it speeding up?

Tags: calculus, physics, kinematics

If the acceleration of a particle is positive and its velocity is negative, is the particle speeding up?

In other words, suppose that

- $y(t)$ is the position at $t$
- $y'(t)<0$
- $y'(t)$ is continuous and differentiable
- $y''(t)\geq0.$

Could the particle be speeding up?

The question originated [here](https://youtu.be/CkePnLcRZuk?t=325).

Comment: Define "*speeding up*". When $y'' \gt 0$ the speed $y'$ is increasing, and since $y' \lt 0$ this means the absolute value of the speed is decreasing.

Comment: The speed is decreasing because the particle is accelerating in the opposite direction of the velocity.

Comment: @JohnDouma The OP wrote that "*its velocity is negative*". When a positive acceleration is applied, that negative velocity is *increasing* towards zero. If what you call "*speed*" is the absolute value of the (negative) velocity then that is indeed *decreasing*. This confusion of semantics is why I asked the OP to clarify what they mean by "*speeding up*".

Comment: @dxiv What else might "speed up" mean other than `move faster (i.e., cover a bigger distance per unit time)`?  I mean, in which contexts would "speed up" not be defined as `increase the absolute value of velocity`?

Comment: @ryang "*Speed up*" is not usually used with negative (or signed) velocities, so I thought asking for clarification of an unusual usage is safer than second-guessing,

Comment: @dxiv Here's my take. The negative sign of velocity is an artifact of the framing, and does not affect the physical scenario that the phrase "speed up" is describing. $\quad$ The phrases "speed up" and "slow down" have clear meanings where the adverbs never refer to spatial direction (so, it is natural to say "slow down" as you are rising *up* the water towards some jellyfish). $\quad$ On the other hand,

Comment: the insertion of the middle word in "speed back up" crucially makes it a fundamentally different phrase: **(1)** here, "up" is matched with "back" instead of "speed", making it a preposition, so refers to spatial direction, **(2)** "speed back up" does not imply a change of speed, only that the motion is upwards (i.e., "speeding *upwards*"). In contrast, the "up" and "down" in "speed up" and "slow down" always refers to direction of speed change, never to spatial direction. $\quad$ So, the phrases "speed downwards" and "speed back down" are never replaced with just "speed down".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a question of semantics and of language usage rather than mathematics. People don’t usually use the phrase “speeding up” in everyday speech when an object’s velocity and acceleration have opposite signs. (In that case, the absolute value of the velocity will be decreasing.) Let’s say I’m playing with one of those toys consisting of a paddle and a ball attached by an elastic cord. As it goes downward, I’d naturally say that it slows down near the bottom of its motion, comes to a stop for a split second, and then speeds up as it starts to ascend.

But mathematically, its acceleration was nearly constant and directed upwards during its reversal of direction. So switching from “slowing down” to “speeding up” is a quirk of language.

To press the point, consider how it looks from another frame of reference. Let’s say I’m doing this in a glass elevator that’s ascending rapidly. Someone outside the elevator just focuses on the ball. (Maybe it glows and everything else is dark.) They see it speeding up the whole time.

This mismatch between everyday usage and mathematics is a broader phenomenon. Especially when it comes to negative numbers. People don’t say “I gained negative $500 on my investments last year”, or “my post got negative 5 likes”, but mathematically we have a single quantity with either positive or negative values.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that people don't use the term "speeding up" in everyday use? Is English not your first language?

Comment: @JohnDouma You left out the last half of my sentence, “when an object’s velocity is negative”. That’s what is known in English as a *restrictive clause*, explained here for instance: https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/pronouns/restrictive-clause/ As they point out, “removing a restrictive clause will typically change a meaning within the sentence”.

Comment: An object that is falling toward Earth under its weight has a negative velocity, (assuming we choose up as the positive axis) and is speeding up because its speed is increasing.

Comment: @JohnDouma You have a point. I’ve made an edit.

Answer (score 3):

Velocity is speed with a direction.  I'm assuming when you say velocity <0, that means a direction is chosen and the particle is moving backwards along that direction while acceleration is adding forward speed to it.  For example, imagine you're in a car facing uphill but rolling backwards down the hill.  Now what happens when you push on the throttle pedal?

Answer (score 0):

> If a particle's acceleration is positive and its velocity is negative, is it speeding up?

A particle's velocity is in its direction of motion, while its acceleration is in the direction of the net force on it.

Therefore, **a particle's acceleration and velocity being in opposite directions means that it must be retarding**, that is, its speed must be decreasing, that is, it must be slowing down.

In your example, the particle is retarding [while](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/585142/8446) having a *positive acceleration*. If this feels surprising, remember that the frame of reference of this 1D motion can be legitimately flipped without changing the scenario, after which the particle will naturally still be retarding, but this time having a positive velocity and a *negative acceleration*.